# SilverStripe enable users to edit SiteConfig

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to enable users to be able to edit open `SiteConfig` section and edit the fields.

I've got the following SiteConfig extension (inside a module)

```
class SiteConfigTweaks extends DataExtension {

  public function canView($member = null) {
      return true;
  }

  public function canEdit($member = null) {
      return true;
  }

  public function canCreate($member = null) {
      return true;
  }
```

Extension declared in .yml file:

```
SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - SiteConfigTweaks
```

The `SiteConfigTweaks` extension is properly extended and tested (other functions in this class work fine). But the permissions settings (`canView` etc) seem to be ineffective.

Comment: Have you added the extension to `SiteConfig` either in YML or PHP? Have you performed a `?flush` to enable it?

Comment: Yes absolutely, other functions within the class are working properly. Updated the OP. Also, this class is placed inside a module if that's relevant.

Comment: Is it possible there is another extension that is setting these to return false, as it could be that a false takes precedent over a true.

Comment: Good call, however this is the only extension that influences `SiteConfig`

Comment: What is it that the user can see (or not see) which users are these? Are they ContentAuthors, ADMINs, something else?

Comment: Are you logged in as Admin when testing this? That might override these settings.

Comment: @DanHensby they are ContentAuthors
@ Janne Klouman I'm logged in as ContentAuthor and the Settings tab is invisible but visible under Admin account

Comment: In the CMS under `Security` -> `Groups` -> `Content Authors` -> `Permissions`, "edit SiteConfig" permission might be un-ticked, and this might override whatever you put in `canX()`?

Comment: Yes! That's it. Seems to be a default value in SS 3.4. If you comment this as an answer I'll tick it off.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't really the solution because the `can` is still being ignored. I think it's being ignored because the default return is false (because this setting is off). So basically, it looks like this can't be done because something else is returning false.

Comment: That's true, if I would move my module to a new SS installation it wouldn't work "out-of-the-box". Any ideas on how to change the default value for this permission setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CMS under `Security > Groups > Content Authors > Permissions`, the "Manage site configuration" permission might be un-ticked, and this might take precedence over the `canX()` functions.